# Java XPath Expression error

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I am trying to print a specific node from my XML data file such as Pantone 100 for example. I would like it to print out all the attributes from pantone 100 such as all the colors and the data they hold but I am unsure of how to format the XPath compile correctly in a way where it will pull only the specific pantone number I'm looking for.

EDIT: The code below outputs null

**XML Data**

```
<inventory>
    <Product pantone="100" blue="7.4" red="35" green="24"> </Product>
    <Product pantone="101" blue="5.4" red="3" rubine="35" purple="24"> </Product>
    <Product pantone="102" orange="5.4" purple="35" white="24"> </Product>
    <Product pantone="103" orange="5.4" purple="35" white="24"> </Product>
    <Product pantone="104" orange="5.4" purple="35" white="24"> </Product>
    <Product pantone="105" orange="5.4" purple="35" white="24"> </Product>
    <Product pantone="106" black="5.4" rubine="35" white="24" purple="35" orange="5.4"> </Product>
</inventory>
```

**Code**

```
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import javax.xml.xpath.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class XPathDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args)
            throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException,
            IOException, XPathExpressionException {

        DocumentBuilderFactory domFactory
                = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        domFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder builder = domFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse("data.xml");
        XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        // XPath Query for showing all nodes value
        XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/inventory/Product[@pantone='100']");

        Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Output
null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Output is null because `getNodeValue` is not applicable here. `getTextContent` would give you the text between the start and end tags, e.g. FOOBAR in this example:

```
<Product pantone="100" blue="7.4" red="35" green="24">FOOBAR</Product>`.
```

However if you want to print all attribute values for your resultset:

```
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList)result;
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++)
    {
        NamedNodeMap a = nodes.item(i).getAttributes();
        for (int j=0; j<a.getLength(); j++)
            System.out.println(a.item(j));
    }
```

or use `a.item(j).getNodeName()` or `a.item(j).getNodeValue()` to retrieve attribute name or value respectively.

Answer (score 3):

I'm no expert with xpath (literally learned about it today) so I am not 100% certain about this, but you have `/inventory/product/pantone/text(@=100)`, instead try this:

```
/inventory/Product[@pantone='100']
```

As I understand it, this will match the `Product` with the attribute `pantone` that equals `"100"`.

As for printing the data, I am not sure, but hopefully this will get you on the right track.

> **Edit:** Check out this page: [`Node`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html). It is the javadoc for the `Node` type. As geert3 said in his/her answer `getNodeValue()` returns the value of the node, which in this case is the value of the element, not the attributes (for example: in `<element>value</element>` the value of the element element is value) which in your case is `null` because it's empty (if it thought the type was String maybe it would be `""` instead of `null`?).
>
> Try calling [`Node#getAttributes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getAttributes%28%29) and then iterating across the [`NamedNodeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/NamedNodeMap.html) with [`NamedNodeMap#item(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/NamedNodeMap.html#item%28int%29) to get the `Node`s. ***These*** should be the attributes (I think, if I am understanding the API correctly). `getNodeName()` should be the name of the attribute (e.g., `pantone`) and `getNodeValue()` should be the value of the attribute (e.g., `100`).

Comment: this seems to work but I get "null" as an output. not sure whats wrong

Comment: @ssj3goku878 I have searched Google for the `Node` javadoc and done my best to update the answer to be what you are looking for. Try that and report back.